# Do not want a parent and its child process to share the same file descriptor table

Tags: c, process

I open a file in program A. Its file descriptor is 3. Using fork followed by an execve I execute another program B, where I immediately open another file. This files descriptor is 4. If A and B was not sharing the file descriptor table then the file descriptor of file opened in B should have been 3. I need to create child processes not sharing the parents address space including open files.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The child *doesn't* share the same FD table, you simply forgot to close them in the child or mark them close-on-exec.

Comment: @lgnacio Thank You. But is there a way where the closing of files take place automatically before it is copied on new process creation.

Comment: Mark them close-on-exec. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643304/how-to-set-close-on-exec-by-default/1644590#1644590

Answer (score 1):

Close the file before `exec`ing the new process.  Do that in the code between the `fork()` and `exec()`.

Comment: Thank You. But is there a way where the closing of files take place automatically before it is copied on new process creation.

Comment: Both answers are correct. I choose the other as it gives me two options. Thank you so much