# How to fork process without inheriting handles?

Tags: c++, c, posix, fork

In my C/C++ server application which runs on Mac (Darwin Kernel Version 10.4.0) I'm forking child processes and want theses childes to not inherit file handles (files, sockets, pipes, ...) of the server. Seems that by default all handles are being inherited, even more, netstat shows that child processes are listening to the server's port. How can I do such kind of fork?

Comment: If you do an `exec()` after `fork()`, maybe this answer is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1644590/1741542

Answer (score 11):

Normally, after `fork()` but before `exec()` one does `getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, fds);` and then closes all file descriptors lower than `fds`.

Also, `close-on-exec` can be set on file descriptors using `fcntl()`, so that they get closed automatically on `exec()`. This, however, is not thread-safe because another thread can `fork()` after this thread opens a new file descriptor but before it sets `close-on-exec` flag.

On Linux this problem has been solved by adding `O_CLOEXEC` flag to functions like `open()` so that no extra call is required to set `close-on-exec` flag.

Comment: If you're going to do `exec`, you can just configure all your FDs to "close on exec". But I was under the impression that the OP wasn't going to `exec` anything...

Comment: @KerrekSB true, but one still may like to do the closing loop just to make sure no file descriptor gets leaked into the new process because setting `close-on-exec` was overlooked somewhere.

Comment: @KerrekSB and you may not control either one of the opens or one of the forks if you call some 3rd party API or even some OS function.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, you need to close them yourself since only you know which ones you need to keep open or not.

Comment: I don't wan't to keep none of them opened. Is there some method for getting the all handles available in child after fork?

Comment: Hmm, well you could just do `for (i=0; i < 1024; ++i) close(i);`, or go higher if you have a whole lot of connections. (Or better yet use `getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, fds);` like @Maxim is using to get the highest fd you can have)

Answer (score 0):

Basically no. You have to do that yourself. Maybe [`pthread_atfork`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_atfork.html) help, but it still be tedious.