# Inherit parent socket in fork() child

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, sockets, fork

I m developing a C application running on linux system (**kernel 3.4.11**)

In my application, I m opening a server socket on a thread. And I m opening a `fork()` in which I execute a shell command with `execvp()` in the main thread.

Opening a `fork()` will inherit the socket file descriptor in the child. And this could cause problems according to many topics on the net. In my case If I close my application I can see with `netstat` that the socket is assigned to another daemon (another random daemon).

In fact there is many solutions for a such issue:

**1)** close the socket on the beginning of the `fork()` child:

```
if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
    return -1;

if (pid == 0) {
    /* child */

    close(socket_desc);
```

**2)** Use `fcntl()` and `FD_CLOEXEC` when opening the socket in the parent

```
socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
fcntl(socket_desc, F_SETFD, fcntl(fd, F_GETFD) | FD_CLOEXEC);
```

**3)** Use `O_CLOEXEC` in the `socket()` function:

```
socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM|O_CLOEXEC , 0);
```

What's the best solution? and why?

Any other better solution is welcome.

Comment: Where did you get (3) from?

Comment: @EJP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643304/how-to-set-close-on-exec-by-default

Comment: #2 is subject to a race condition. Another thread could fork/exec in between the socket() and the fcntl().

Answer (score 3):

If you control all the code, these make no difference.

Use the first solution if someone else gives you a `socket` you don't know how it was created.

Use the second, if you write a module to which someone else transmit you a socket, and you want to pass it to another module you don't control but you suspect to `fork()/exec()`.

Use the third if you are the creator of the socket and need to pass it to another module that you suspect to `fork()/exec()`.